# CMake unresolved external symbol with subproject on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I have a rather simple **top-level** CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(MyProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(Api)
add_subdirectory(Cli)
```

containing 2 subdirectories Api and Cli.

The API CMakeLists.txt is rather simple also:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_library(Api
    api.h
    api.cpp
    API_global.h)

target_link_libraries(Api Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)
add_compile_definitions(API_LIBRARY)
```

The sources are trivial:

API_global.h

```
#ifndef API_GLOBAL_H
#define API_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(API_LIBRARY)
#define API_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define API_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // API_GLOBAL_H
```

API.h

```
#ifndef API_H
#define API_H

#include "API_global.h"

class API_EXPORT API
{
public:
    API() = default;
    void printHello() const;
};

#endif // API_H
```

api.cpp

```
#include "api.h"
void API::printHello() const {}
```

The CLI subproject CMakeLists.txt then simply calls

```
find_library(API Api HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Api)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Api)
target_link_libraries(cli PUBLIC ${API})
```

Within main.cpp a call to printHello fails with

```
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl API::printHello(void)const " (__imp_?printHello@API@@QEBAXXZ) referenced in function main
```

I first tested this on Mac where all is good. Fiddling around with this setup on Windows the entire morning but I cannot get my head around it. The `find_library` is returning the Api.lib as expected. My first guess would be that the API_LIBRARY is still defined in the Cli subproject but this is not the case apparently.
I must be missing something very obvious!

Comment: try use `target_compile_definitions` to add definition to library target exactly if you are not sure.

Comment: `target_compile_definitions(Api PRIVATE API_LIBRARY)` does not help, unfortunately

Comment: Examine `.lib` file of your `Api` library and check, whether it actually exports ``printHello`` method. BTW, linking with the library created in the CMake project doesn't require `find_library` call. Just use the name of the library **target**: `target_link_libraries(cli PUBLIC Api)`.

Comment: just using `target_link_libraries(cli PUBLIC Api)` works but I really don't understand why `find_library` was not. Thanks

Comment: Call to ``target_link_libraries(cli PUBLIC ${API})`` doesn't adjust **dependencies** between `cli` and `Api`. Probably, you have updated the code of the library, but file `.lib` is not updated because of absence of dependencies. The call `target_link_libraries(cli PUBLIC Api)` adjusts proper dependencies, so before building `cli`, the library `Api` is rebuilt.